# How to use Imacros if/else statement to run a macro

Tags: jquery, macros, imacros

I am new to imacros and struggling to find a solution to run macros by statement.

'If there is this "TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=HREF:/pnt/*/"

then I would like to run only 
"TAG POS=2 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:NoFormName ATTR=* CONTENT=abcde"

If no, then running only "TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:Takip "

Could anyone help me with eval creation please ?

Answer (score 2):

To solve such issues, you may use a certain workaround. Something like this:

```
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 0
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=HREF:/pnt/*/ EXTRACT=HTM
SET true EVAL("('{{!EXTRACT}}' == '#EANF#') ? 'false' : '';")
SET false EVAL("('{{!EXTRACT}}' == '#EANF#') ? '' : 'true';")
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
TAG POS=2{{true}} TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:NoFormName ATTR=* CONTENT=abcde
TAG POS=1{{false}} TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:Takip
SET !ERRORIGNORE NO
SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 6
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but it is not working. I could not get it working

Comment: Maybe the task is slightly different then you described above. Anyway take a look at the Scripting Interfaces. For example, at [this one](http://wiki.imacros.net/Firefox#Javascript_Scripting_Interface) working in 'iMacros for Firefox'.